# Identification: moving and stacking black and white pieces, packed in a tube

Tags: identify-this-game, two-player

My parents had this game, all I can remember:

- It was stored in a brownish cardboard tube, about 10 cm in diameter and 50 cm long.
- It consists of a playing mat (might have been artificial leather) and cylindrical wooden pieces of about 3 cm diameter, 1,5 cm height.
- There were black and white wooden pieces for the two players, maybe some more of a third color.
- The pieces were moved across the board and the game was about stacking them, using your own and the opponent's pieces.
- Probably from the late seventies, early eighties.
- Germany
- quite unsure: winning had something to do with tower heights, maybe points were awarded depending on the level that the pieces were on.

Comment: do you recall the win condition(s)?

Comment: very unsure, but i guess it was about tower heights. see edit

Comment: What does the playing mat look like? The description sounds like checkers. Could you highlight the differences and similarities between that game and checkers?

Comment: Agree, very generic :) Could also be backgammon if the stacking was not 3d.  Were there dice involved?

Answer (score 1):

Any of these match?
[BGG geeklist of games in tubes](https://boardgamegeek.com/geeklist/5846/totally-tubular-games)

Also from the description sounds a lot like [DVONN](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/2346/dvonn), but it didn't use tube packaging

Comment: "A brownish carboard tube" without identifiaction suggests a home made container for the game.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [Polarity](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/380/polarity)?

- black and white (and one red) discs stored in tube
- played on (in my version) a canvas mat
- points scored by towers that stacked, and the pieces moved across the board because they were magnetic and attracted/repelled each other

The key extras would be:

- discs were magnetic
- A play was to "lean" a disc against the magnetic field of another leaner or single, or a tower (created by leaners being "caught")
- if you caused anything to snap or fall, your turn ends (and if you created or added to a tower, it is flipped to the opponent's colour)

Comment: Looks extremely interesting, but no. The pieces were made of wood, I added this to the description.